# How can I get data from API using php form

Tags: php, forms, api

I have an API for decoding qr codes.
There is a form that sends a picture from a device to a server.
After submit it redirects to another page and prints JSON string on the screen, but I need to write it in a variable in index file.
There is a way to use file_get_contents() function to decode qr code from the Internet, but I can't use it for local images.

```
<html>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://api.qrserver.com/v1/read-qr-code/" method="POST">
<!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE (maximum file size in bytes) must precede the file input field used to upload the QR code image -->
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1048576" />
<!-- The "name" of the input field has to be "file" as it is the name of the POST parameter -->
Choose QR code image to read/scan: <input name="file" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Read QR code" />
</form>
</html>
```

Link to API documentation: http://goqr.me/api/doc/read-qr-code/

Comment: What about AJAX

Comment: I'm a beginner in web and don't know how it can be useful.
I would be grateful if you can advise anything

Comment: If you want to run the API in PHP, use cURL for example. cURL is usually already on the server. Here are examples: https://www.php.net/manual/de/curl.examples.php My tip: Use a debugger to see the API responses. If you have questions afterwards, open a new question with the previous html and your new PHP lines that you have already written.

Comment: If you use AJAX, you submit the form to the API using JavaScript. The JSON response then comes back to yore page in a JavaScript variable. The page itself does not change or refresh. You can then use JavaScript code to display the response data on the current page, if it want to. If you don't know anything about Ajax you can study it in many, many tutorials

Comment: Okay, thanks! 
Will try to solve it